# How to print DWG file from Java

Tags: java, dwg

How do I print a .dwg file from Java?

Is there is an API for accessing and passing the DWG AutoCAD file to the printer for printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dwglib](http://jdwglib.sourceforge.net/) is a Java library for accesing DWG files. It is essentially a port from the Pythoncad DWG reading classes by Art Haas. jdwglib manages complex DWG objects allowing users to employ these objects directly in their applications.

Answer (score 0):

You'll to find an API that allows you to read an AutoCAD dwg file.  I haven't seen any Java ones, but you might be able to start from the .NET one following:

http://code.google.com/p/tf-net/wiki/DwgReaderWriter

Once you've found an API, then it might be as simple as printing whatever you render.